# jquery ui tabs slidedown, slideup effect

Tags: jquery, user-interface, tabs, hide, show

I have added jQuery tabs and the effect I want to achieve is the slide down and slide up action. Right now when you go to the page it defaults as one is always open. How do I make it so that they default as closed? Here is the code

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $( ".tabs" ).tabs({
show: {effect: 'slideDown'},
hide: {effect: 'slideUp'}

});
({
collapsible: true, active : 'none'
});
return false;
});

/*-------HTML-----------*/

<ul>
<li class="button"><a href="#tabs1">WHAT'S IN THE BAG</a></li>
<li class="button"><a href="#tabs3">PLAYER HISTORY</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="slidingDiv" data-role="collapsible">CONTENT</div>
<div class="slidingDiv2" data-role="collapsible">CONTENT</div>
```

Comment: Can you please post you HTML please.

Comment: I updated with a brief snippit of my code. The html is more detailed because it uses php to call items from wordpress.

Comment: Jut to help you going I have made for you a working example. https://jsfiddle.net/upjkm2b3/1/. I don't work with wordpress so I think you will know beter than me how to integrate it in your code :)

Comment: Thank you for creating that, Franco but what I am looking for is something different but I will definitely use this for reference in the future.

Comment: I made for you a new example have a look here: https://jsfiddle.net/upjkm2b3/6/

Comment: I made a new fiddle for you. You can elaborate this one. I think this is what you were looking for.